# Imagine library not working in shared hosting

Tags: symfony

So I was developing a site that needed image resize so I decided to use avalanche123/imagine-bundle which uses the imagine library
In my local everything worked perfectly and then I uploaded the project to a shared hosting
When I go to the url generated by imagine bundle prints a zero
So I tried to find out where the problem is and I found it executes until this line

```
$image = $this->imagine->open($sourcePath);
```

$this->imagine is an object with class Imagine\Image\ImagineInterface

So when this line is executed it just returns 0
No exception is thrown and nothing is shown in logs
And I don't really know how imagine works inside and it seems no one else had this problem
So does anyone know what's the cause?

Comment: Get yourself a decent hosting like a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) — it's really [cheap](http://www.hetzner.de/en/hosting/produktmatrix_vserver/vserver-produktmatrix).

Comment: Em I have a dedicated server ;). This project is for a company that already has a shared hosting and doesn't sound like to pay more for hosting

Answer (score 0):

The [AvalancheImagineBundle](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle) uses the [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) PHP library to compute images. As stated in the [README](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/blob/develop/README.md):

> Depending on the chosen Image implementation, you may need one of the
>   following:
>
> - GD2
> - Imagick
> - Gmagick

It seems that you can choose the driver with the following configuration:

```
avalanche_imagine:
    driver: gd
```

The value can be `gd`, `imagick` or `gmagick` and `gd` seems to be the default. Go ahead and see if any of this three is installed on the shared host by outputting `phpinfo();`. Just search for the particular string and see if it is avaiable.

Comment: I already did that. gd is installed and it's a compatible version with what I saw from imagine code